# Multiple joins with jooq

Tags: java, sql, join, jooq

How to join 6 and more Tables using jooq? 
I have this tables: TPI, TPIREV, COSTCENTER, DEPARTMENT, CUSTOMER, TRANSACTIONNUMBER.

I try to implement this sql query (first without cases):

```sql
select
    case
        when TPI.TPINumber is null then ''
        else TPI.TPINumber
    end as C0,
    case
        when _J0.description is not null then _J0.description
        else TPI.description
    end as C1,
    TPI.TPIType as C2,
    _J4.description as C3,
    _J0.deactivationDate as C4,
    _J6.timestamp as C5,
    TPI.id as C6
from
    TPI
inner join TPIRev as _J0 on
    (TPI.activeVersion = _J0.id)
left join CostCenter as _J7 on
    (_J0.costCenter = _J7.id
    and (_J7.mandant = 1))
left join Department as _J8 on
    (_J7.department = _J8.id
    and (_J8.mandant = 1))
left join Customer as _J4 on
    (_J8.customer = _J4.id
    and (_J4.mandant = 1))
left join TransactionNumber as _J6 on
    (_J0.transactionNumber = _J6.id)
where
    ( TPI.mandant = 1
    and TPI.active = true )
order by
    C0
limit 10
```

So I try this like:

```java
Tpi tpi = TPI.as("tpi");
Tpirev tpirev = TPIREV.as("tpirev");
Costcenter costcenter = COSTCENTER.as("costcenter");
Department department = DEPARTMENT.as("department");
Customer customer = CUSTOMER.as("customer");
Transactionnumber transactionnumber = TRANSACTIONNUMBER.as("transactionnumber");

dsl.select(tpi.TPINUMBER, tpi.TPITYPE, tpi.ID)
.from(tpi)
.innerJoin(tpirev).on(tpi.ACTIVEVERSION.eq(tpirev.ID))
.leftJoin(costcenter).on(tpirev.COSTCENTER.eq(costcenter.ID).and(costcenter.MANDANT.eq(Long.valueOf(1))
.leftJoin(department).on(costcenter.DEPARTMENT.equal(department.ID).and(department.MANDANT).equal(Long.valueOf(1))
.leftJoin(customer).on(department.CUSTOMER).equal(customer.ID).and(customer.MANDANT).equal(Long.valueOf(1))
.leftJoin(transactionnumber).on(tpirev.TRANSACTIONNUMBER).equal(transactionnumber.ID)
.where(tpi.MANDANT.equal(Long.valueOf(1)).and(tpi.ACTIVE.eq(true)))
.limit(10)
.fetch();
```

But it looks like it's not possible to use more than two joins at once. Should I split this joins like in this example? [How to join 3 tables and iterate results using jooq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385248/how-to-join-3-tables-and-iterate-results-using-jooq)
Or there is another way to solve it? Please advise.

So, I've solved the problem and the result code looks like:

```java
dsl.select(
DSL.case_()
        .when(tpi.TPINUMBER.isNotNull(), tpi.TPINUMBER).otherwise(" ").as(tpi.TPINUMBER),
DSL.case_()
        .when(tpirev.DESCRIPTION.isNotNull(), tpirev.DESCRIPTION).otherwise(tpi.DESCRIPTION),
tpi.TPITYPE, 
customer.DESCRIPTION, 
tpirev.DEACTIVATIONDATE, 
transactionnumber.TIMESTAMP, 
tpi.ID)     
.from(tpi)
.innerJoin(tpirev).on(tpi.ACTIVEVERSION.eq(tpirev.ID))
.leftJoin(costcenter).on(tpirev.COSTCENTER.eq(costcenter.ID).and(costcenter.MANDANT.eq(Long.valueOf(1))))
.leftJoin(department).on(costcenter.DEPARTMENT.eq(department.ID).and(department.MANDANT.eq(Long.valueOf(1))))
.leftJoin(customer).on(department.CUSTOMER.eq(customer.ID).and(customer.MANDANT.eq(Long.valueOf(1))))
.leftJoin(transactionnumber).on(tpirev.TRANSACTIONNUMBER.eq(transactionnumber.ID))
.where(tpi.MANDANT.equal(Long.valueOf(1)).and(tpi.ACTIVE.eq(true)))
.orderBy(tpi.TPINUMBER)
.limit(10);
```

I hope it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not possible"? You can join as many tables as you want in jOOQ. There is no such limitation.

Comment: @Lukas Eder Thank you for reply, you are right, it's possible. I just couldn't find any example with more than 2-3 joins at once. I was with wrong with brackets, my first query with jooq :) and eclipse was somehow not really helpful.

Comment: I see :) Yes those brackets can get in the way when doing some more heavy nesting...